# Deleting svn checkout with NAnt

Tags: svn, nant

I am attempting to delete a folder that is a svn checkout of my project so that I can do a fresh checkout. The problem is whenever I try to delete this folder using a nant delete task I keep getting the following error:

```
[delete] Deleting directory 'C:\projects\my_project\Trunk'.

BUILD FAILED

c:\Projects\my_project\default.build(63,4):
Cannot delete directory 'C:\projects\my_project\Trunk\SomeFolder\AnotherFolder'.
    The directory is not empty.
```

Is there a trick to delete a working copy with nant here? I tried doing a delete targeting only the .svn directories, but nant wouldn't delete all of them for some reason. Here is the task I was using for that, but it didn't work:

```
    <delete>
        <fileset basedir="myproject\trunk">
            <include name="\**\.svn" />
        </fileset>
    </delete>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

@jitter, you were very close

first there is no dirset, I got an error when attempting to use this. here is what actually worked

```
<delete>
  <fileset basedir="myproject\trunk" defaultexcludes="false">
    <include name="**/.svn" />
    <include name="**/.svn/**/*" />
  </fileset>
</delete>
```

fileset will include directories if you have the correct selections. I think the key was using d`efaultexcludes="false"` and using

```
**/.svn/**/*
```

which properly selects subfolder of the .svn folders.

Thanks!

Comment: Well I neither have .NET nor NAnt installed and just wrote that by the documentation on their site. And there is a dirset. http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/types/dirset.html. And in the CVS too http://nant.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nant/nant/src/NAnt.Core/Types/DirSet.cs?revision=1.2&view=markup. Maybe that added that in a recent version

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the whole trunk directory

```
<delete dir="myproject/trunk" />
```

I can't verify right now if `<include ... />` is even able to select directories not files.

Else if you just want to delete the .svn directories

```
<delete>
    <dirset basedir="myproject\trunk" defaultexcludes="false">
        <include name="**/.svn" />
    </dirset>
</delete>
```

I used `dirset` as I'm not sure if `fileset` even selects directories. Maybe it gets interpreted as "give me all files which are named *.svn*"
Notice the use of `defaultexcludes="false"` and check here [`<fileset documentation>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/types/fileset.html) what the defaultexcludes are (e.g. `**/.svn` exactly what you tried to include)